# Screen Reader on Linux system

Tags: linux, gnome3, chrome, accessibility

I switched **on** the screen reader on my Ubuntu 17.10 machine. It works fine with Firefox 61.0.1 (64-bit), but its not working with Chrome version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Is there need of any other installation?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 17.10 uses Gnome Shell instead of Unity and the screen reader built into Gnome is known as [Orca](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Orca). In order for a screen reader to get information from a browser, the browser needs to implement the operating system's accessibility API. You should also make sure that you start the screen reader before you launch the browser, because, for performance reasons, browsers tend to check whether an assistive technology is running before deciding whether to expose their accessibility API.

Firefox has documented its [support for accessibility APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/AT-APIs), which includes ATK/AT-SPI on Linux (in addition to APIs for Windows and Mac OS).

For Chromium, a [bug about Orca support](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24585) was submitted as long ago as 2009 and it is still open. [Chromium's Accessibility Technical Documentation](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/accessibility) has a section on API support which points out that its ATK support is "very limited".

Conclusion: if you are a screen reader on Linux, Chromium and Chrome are not a good choice.

**Update (20.10.2020)**: In Chromium's documentation, ATK support is still described as "very limited". However, [Issue 24585](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24585) (mentioned above) has been worked on, and as a consequence of work on [Issue 977112](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=977112), users will no longer need to manually pass `--force-renderer-accessibility` in order to enable screenreader support.